# How to record PC screen activity with a DVR?

Tags: video-streaming, dvr, surveillance, cctv

I was asked how would one be able to record PC screen activity to a standalone DVR (to sync it with CCTV cameras).

2 different solutions came to my mind:

- A software installed on the PC makes the PC to pretend to be an IP camera, streaming desktop activity over the network to a DVR
- There is a splitter cable attached to the PC's VGA or DVI ouput port. One fork would go to monitor and the other to DVR

Unfortunately, googling for any of these solutions was a dead end for me: I couldn't find any software which would turn a PC's desktop to an IP camera feed nor any DVR which would accept DVI or VGA input.

Does such software exist? Or perhaps does a DVR with a VGA or DVI input exist? Or is there some third way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about a VGA to composite converter? There are many such devices sold on Ebay for example, beginning at approx 16 USD - just have a look [here](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trkparms=65%253A16%257C66%253A1%257C39%253A1&rt=nc&_nkw=vga%20to%20composite%20converter&_sticky=1&_stpos=&_trksid=p3286.c0.m14&gbr=1&_sop=15&_sc=1). Just be careful - the cheapest ones are only cables while you need converter box - for example [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/PC-MAC-VGA-TV-AV-Composite-RCA-S-Video-Converter-Adapter-Switch-Box-M-/250986780078?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a6ffa55ae). I assume, that the DVR has composite input - S-Video so this could be solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Connect VGA splitter 1 output to PC monitor and another to VGA-PAL converter. Get AV output from VGA-PAL converter, connect to DRV.